# Merge Github repo with old PyCharm project

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I have an old Github repo which I used to update by uploading files. The project is getting bigger and I now want to use a VCS (should've done this from the beginning).

Is there a way of merging my current PyCharm Project to my already created GitHub repo, so that I can commit/push any future changes?

Comment: What issues are you running and what have you tried? If i understand what you're asking properly, then you should just be able to clone your repo locally, copy/paste your pycharm project into the repo cloned, organize it as you like, and then push/commit your changes.

Comment: @EdwardRomero Yep I think you got it. But is there no way of doing this without cloning the repo locally? So instead just adding the GitHub repo in settings somewhere so that they are integrated?

Comment: Is your pycharm another github repo and you want to merge both repos? or you have a repo and some project locally and you want to merge those?

Comment: @EdwardRomero The latter... I have a repo and a project (They have basically the same code/files in) and I want to merge them. Sorry if it wasn't clear, and thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, I would just clone the repo locally and merge the files that need to be updated. Trying to figure out how to merge all of it in one go will probs end up messing with your git history